# CSS Float Horizontal Overflow

Tags: html, css, recursion, overflow

I have the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CLight/1emh82cv/

This is a recursive structure where it consists of two twin cells sharing the top row, and one cell in the second/bottom row. The three cells will be recursively inserted into the bottom cell. **I am trying to figure out how to make the cells expand horizontally when they overflow, without breaking the structure.** Thanks a bunch.

Here's the html:

```
 <div class="cell-main">
  <div class="cell-left">
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestte
  </div>
  <div class="cell-right">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="cell-bottom">
    <div class="cell-left">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="cell-right">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="cell-bottom">

      <div class="cell-left">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="cell-right">
        test
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell-left {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align:left
}

.cell-right {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;

    float: left;
    text-align:right
}

.cell-bottom {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 94%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
}

.cell-main {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

EDIT: Updated jsfiddle and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for the [**`overflow-wrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) property.

> The **overflow-wrap** CSS property specifies whether or not the browser should insert line breaks within words to prevent text from overflowing its content box. (Mozilla MDN)

This property can have the following values, in case you need it recursive, the global values can be interesting for you:

```
/* Keyword values */
overflow-wrap: normal;
overflow-wrap: break-word;

/* Global values */
overflow-wrap: inherit;
overflow-wrap: initial;
overflow-wrap: unset;
```

If you want to keep the height of the parcel use `overflow: auto` on the main `div`'s.

See my code snippet!

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.cell-left {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align:left
}

.cell-right {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50%;

    float: left;
    text-align:right
}

.cell-bottom {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 94%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
}

.cell-main {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell-main">
  <div class="cell-left">
    testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestte
  </div>
  <div class="cell-right">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="cell-bottom">
    <div class="cell-left">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="cell-right">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="cell-bottom">

      <div class="cell-left">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="cell-right">
        test
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @felix-häberle. Unfortunately, line breaks are not an option for me. I am trying to make the cells expand horizontally. Is that possible?

Comment: I figured it out. Your solution pointed me to the right direction. Turns out 'overflow: auto' on the main div is all what I needed. Thanks!